# IEnumerable Where clause

Tags: c#, ienumerable

```
Line 1 - A 01/01/2012 01/05/2012  
Line 2 - B 01/01/2012 01/05/2012  
Line 3 - A 01/06/2012 01/07/2012  
Line 4 - A 01/01/2012 01/05/2012  
Line 5 - A 01/06/2012 01/07/2012
```

I am bundling this list with the following method

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Line>> Bundle(IEnumerable<Line> Lines)
    {
        yield return Lines
        .Where(x => x.PropertyOne = "A" )
    }
```

I also want to compare if the `Propertytwo` and `Propertythree` are equal, I want a result like below

```
Lines  
----Line 1 - A 01/01/2012 01/05/2012  
----Line 4 - A 01/01/2012 01/05/2012  
Lines  
----Line 3 - A 01/06/2012 01/07/2012            
----Line 5 - A 01/06/2012 01/07/2012
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `x.PropertyOne == "A"` instead of `=`?

Comment: You are right. It is a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a yield return, you probably want to use GroupBy. Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Line>> Bundle(IEnumerable<Line> Lines)
{
    return Lines
        .Where(x => x.PropertyOne == "A" )
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.PropertyTwo, x.PropertyThree});
}
```